# Using arrays in SCSS

Tags: css, arrays, svg, sass

I use SVG-Icons and build them by using the following code:

```
$icon-heart-white:get-colored-icon("heart", "#{$white}");
$icon-heart-primary:get-colored-icon("heart", "#{$primary}");
$icon-heart-secondary:get-colored-icon("heart", "#{$secondary}");
$icon-printer-white:get-colored-icon("printer", "#{$white}");
$icon-printer-secondary:get-colored-icon("printer", "#{$secondary}");
```

How can i minimize the code by using arrays? Something like:

```
$icons: (
    heart: (
        white, primary, secondary
    ),
    printer: (
        white, secondary
    )
);
```

Or maybe i can expand my Array and function i use right now:

```
$path: (
        "heart": "<path fill-rule='evenodd' d='M8 2.748l-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z'/>",
        "printer": "<path d='M11 2H5a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v2H3V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h6a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2h-1V3a1 1 0 0 0-1-1zm3 4H2a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v3a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h1v1H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V7a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v3a2 2 0 0 1-2 2h-1v-1h1a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V7a1 1 0 0 0-1-1z'/><path fill-rule='evenodd' d='M11 9H5a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v3a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1v-3a1 1 0 0 0-1-1zM5 8a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v3a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2v-3a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H5z'/><path d='M3 7.5a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0z'/>"
)

@function get-colored-icon($icon, $color) {
  $string: "<svg viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='" + $color + "' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>" + map-get( $path, $icon ) + "</svg>";
    $string: "url(\"data:image/svg+xml," + $string + "\")";
    
  @return $string;
}
```

Sorry my english isnt that perfect, hope u understand my issue, thanks for your solutions.

Comment: Using loops only works, if there's some sort of rythm. It'd work, but it would be a really imperfect approach. What's wrong about the second solution? Add a `;` after the closing bracket of the map and it works.

Comment: Of course the "second solution" works, i use it!!! (with a `;` after closing bracket) But i want to reduce the first part of code by using another function or array.

Comment: That isn't possible, how do you want to shrink the content you give the function to work with?